# How I can show output in multi line in django? '\n' does not work

Tags: python, django, vscode-debugger

I'm writing a simple django view in VSCode and I want write my HttpRespose in multi line, but it does not work? what is wrong?

*none of Escape Codes works!*

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("firstline. \nanother line!!!!")
```

**I expect the output of**

```
firstline.
another line!!!
```

**but it output is**

```
firstline. another line
```

Comment: use <br/>. `return HttpResponse("firstline. <br/>another line!!!!")`.

Comment: Well the `\n` actually *does* render a new line. BUt the browser simply ignores that. If you however return a "raw text" stream, etc. then it shows the new line.

Answer (score 0):

You return response to the browser.
The browser understands html.
So you need to return the "br" tag instead /n
Try this:

```
def index(request):
   return HttpResponse("firstline. <br/>another line!!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output plain text you can do so by adding the proper mime type. This way the browser will not do html formatting.

```
def index(request):
   return HttpResponse("firstline. \nanother line!!!!", content_type="text/plain")
```